# Extending Twig's AppVariable

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've inherited a website that uses Symfony 2.

The site was working fine until I ran composer to upgrade packages. It upgraded Symfony 2.6 to 2.7.1 and Twig 1.18 to 1.18.2.

I now get the following error:

> Method "site" for object "Symfony\Bridge\Twig\AppVariable" does not exist in @Page/Page/homepage.html.twig at line 21

The twig file in question has calls like this:

```
{{ app.site.name }}
```

Now obviously `site` is not a member of the `AppVariable` type. I'm having trouble figuring out how the original developers managed to extend Twig's `app` global with a new member. I don't really know where to look. I'm not overly competent with Symfony.

Comment: You could use a twig global variable instead:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html

I suspect Symfony\Bridge\Twig\AppVariable to be the app variable

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't figure out what broke. I ended up replacing all of the `{{ app.site.whatever }}` stuff with a twig extension that provided functions for these things.

Comment: actually it is http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/GlobalVariables.html

Try to extend it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What probably was done by the old developers was overriding the `app` variable. Until Symfony @2.7 the class was called `GlobalVariables` and lives in the following namespace - `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating`. As of @2.7 it's called `AppVariable` and it lives in this namespace - `Symfony\Bridge\Twig`. What is done behind the scenes?

That class containing the global variables is simply added as twig global variable using the method `addGlobal` of Twig and for the value of `app` they inject the whole class as a service that's already defined. `GlobalVariables` or `AppVariables` accepts the service container as an argument and defines 5 methods by default that can be used in our templates. I will show you a simple way of extending that class, so you can use it to investigate.

Create simple class that we will define as a service:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\GlobalVariables,
    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class SuperGlobalsExtended extends GlobalVariables {

    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     **/
    protected $container = null;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
        $this->container = $container;

        parent::__construct($container);
    }

}
```

Then register it:

```
services:
    app.super_globals_extended:
        class: AppBundle\Service\SuperGlobalsExtended
        arguments:
            - @service_container
```

And last but not least, override the `app` variable of twig:

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        app: @app.super_globals_extended
```

Now you can define your own methods in your extended class as well as accessing the previous methods that were already here.

For symfony @2.7 is the same, just the class name is different. Here I extend the `GlobalVariables`, but for @2.7 you have to extend `AppVariable`.

Definition of the service for @2.7 located in TwigBundle Resources folder.

```
<service id="twig" class="%twig.class%">
        <argument type="service" id="twig.loader" />
        <argument /> <!-- Twig options -->
        <call method="addGlobal">
            <argument>app</argument>
            <argument type="service" id="twig.app_variable" />
        </call>
        <configurator service="twig.configurator.environment" method="configure" />
    </service>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

**Refer to [Artamiels answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30931869/486917) as a starting point.**

Looks like with sf3, the `AppVariable` class does no longer need the container (and does not have a `parent::__construct`) but the interesting vars are being set directly.

So, I did set my `class MyAppExtension extends AppVariable` with this setup in `services.yml`:

```
extended_twig_app:
  class: AppBundle\Twig\MyAppExtension
  public: false
  calls:
    - [setEnvironment, ["%kernel.environment%"]]
    - [setDebug, ["%kernel.debug%"]]
    - [setTokenStorage, ['@security.token_storage']]
    - [setRequestStack, ['@request_stack']]
```

This is basically xml->yml converted of the coresponding code in the Twig Bundle:
https://github.com/symfony/twig-bundle/blob/master/Resources/config/twig.xml

```
    <service id="twig.app_variable" class="Symfony\Bridge\Twig\AppVariable" public="false">
        <call method="setEnvironment"><argument>%kernel.environment%</argument></call>
        <call method="setDebug"><argument>%kernel.debug%</argument></call>
        <call method="setTokenStorage"><argument type="service" id="security.token_storage" on-invalid="ignore" /></call>
        <call method="setRequestStack"><argument type="service" id="request_stack" on-invalid="ignore" /></call>
    </service>
```